# command or script to move sub-subdirectory (if found) to its parent?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a directory, Movies which contains many subdirectories, [MovieName]. Some of these [MovieName] subdirectories have a randomly named subdirectory with a VIDEO_TS subdirectory inside it. If I find VIDEO_TS, I'd like to move it to the [MovieName] parent of the parent directory and delete the current randomly named parent directory. If I don't find VIDEO_TS 2 layers down, I want to delete [MovieName]. To clarify...

```
Argo
  |-- ASDFJK
         |-- VIDEO_TS 
Birdcage
  |-- B7YEQ
         |-- [a few files - no VIDEO_TS]
```

Since Argo has a VIDEO_TS sub-subdirectory, move it to Argo and delete ASDFJK. Since Birdcage doesn't have a VIDEO_TS, delete Birdcage. I've tried all sorts of things using find and -exec with {} but at best, I can only manage to move VIDEO_TS up one level (which leaves me a ton of cleanup still to do).

Comment: Your desired task, "move `VIDEO_TS` to parent dir && delete parent dir, unless `VIDEO_TS` doesn't exist && delete parent dir" is too complex a task for `find` with `{}`. Use `find -exec` to execute a `bash` script where this task is easier to express.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should get the job done. Try it and when you are satisfied with the results, remove the comments `#` to do the actual job.

## Back up your `Movies` directory before running the script on it. Please...

To create and use the script file, please follow these steps:

1. Create and edit the script file in your home directory by running the following command in the terminal:

   `nano ~/my_script.sh`
2. Copy and paste the following code into the editor changing `/full/path/to/movies/` with the full path to your `Movies` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/full/path/to/movies/"

for directory in $(find "$path" -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -type d -name "VIDEO_TS")
do

        parent=$(dirname $(dirname "$directory"))

        parent2=$(dirname "$directory")

        echo "$directory" " Will be copied to " " $parent "
        echo "$parent2" " Will be deleted!"

#       cp -Rp "$directory" "$parent"

#       rm -rf "$parent2"

done


for directory in $(find "$path" -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -type d ! -name "VIDEO_TS")
do

        parent=$(dirname $(dirname "$directory"))

        echo "$parent" " Will be deleted!"

#       rm -rf "$parent" 

done
```

3. Save the script file and exit the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd>.
4. Make the script file executable by running the following command in the terminal:

   `chmod +x ~/my_script.sh`
5. Run the script by running the following command in the terminal:

   `bash ~/my_script.sh`

Done

Best of luck